# nginx is not compressing response by default when acting as a reverse proxy

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy, compression, ubuntu-11.10

I have nginx sitting on port 80, redirecting requests to a play framework server [as described by deployment docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/production#server).

I have verified that the server by default does not compress by doing the [steps provided by zoul in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140178/how-can-i-tell-if-my-server-is-serving-gzipped-content). However as in the question when passed that gzip is supported, content is compressed.

[There is also this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/360473/gzip-compression-doesnt-work-in-nginx-reverse-proxy-setup) who fixed it by doing a full restart. This however does not work for me.

I suspect that Acceptable encoding is dropped somewhere, however I dont know how to check/fix it.

Can anyone provide clues?
Thanks.

Unbuntu 11.10, with nginx 1.2
The /etc/nginx/nginx.conf snippet is as follows (if needed).

```
##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
expires modified +168h;
```

Comment: Are you using it within the proper context? (i.e. within http {} or deeper)

Comment: @Sašo: Yeah, I am using it as part of http context. I basically uncommented the section which came commented in the default nginx.conf.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have gzip installed and working on your server first. If Gzip is not working or if there is any other conflict, then the process won't work even when you uncomment these lines in nginx conf.

Comment: I will verify. As of now, it still doesn't gzip properly, so probably that might be a clue.

Comment: If you can't try troubleshooting with Gzip, there are other workarounds on the internet for your desired operating systems.

Make sure all your supporting modules are on and that they don't conflict with each other.